# Escaping characters in large XML files

Tags: xml, parsing

I have large XML files of 100s of MB.

Are there any utilities that can parse XML files and escape special charaters in strings without opening the entire file into memory at once?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following c++ program copies a file byte by byte, and it uses very little memory (which makes it a little bit slow).
You can improve the performance by not flushing to the outfile that often.

```
// copy a file using associated buffer's members
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    char ch;
    ifstream infile;
    ofstream outfile;

    infile.open ("original.xml",std::ifstream::binary);
    outfile.open ("copy.xml",std::ofstream::binary);

    while ( !infile.eof() )
    {
        infile >> ch;
        outfile << ch;
        outfile.flush();
    }

    outfile.close();
    infile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

If you want a unix tool, I guess you could use [sed](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-sed2.html).

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if I can hack something together with this.

Comment: This is just a file copy program, not an XML parser.

Comment: I used this, just detected whenever a special character was in a string and I escaped it. Only problem is now I need to get it to work in unicode.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, don't use the DOM. Use SAX or StaX. If not in Java, you can still use SAX either with MSXML or with Expat.

Answer (score 1):

SAX and StAX may work if the stuff you do is very simple, otherwise, VTD-XML is the best bet

[Introduction to VTD-XML](http://java.dzone.com/articles/introduction-vtd-xml)

Comment: Why not give an example of using VTD-XML to solve the problem?

Comment: did you see the reference to an introductory article?